# 2D arrays in JSON getting converted into a 1D array of objects

Tags: php, json

I've looked around but haven't found an answer so I figured i would give it an ask myself.

I've noticed that a round trip to JSON converts a 2-D array into a 1D array of Objects.

Is there any way around this or should I just try to work with objects from the beginning (e.g. $test->1->4 ? see example below

```
    $test = array();
    $test[0][0] = "0-0";
    $test[0][2] = "0-2";
    $test[1][1] = "1-1";
    $test[1][2] = "1-2";
    var_dump($test);
    $encoded = json_encode($test);
    var_dump($encoded);
    $recreated = json_decode($encoded);
    var_dump($recreated);
```

outputs

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "0-0"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "0-2"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [1]=>
    string(3) "1-1"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "1-2"
  }
}
string(45) "[{"0":"0-0","2":"0-2"},{"1":"1-1","2":"1-2"}]"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#19 (2) {
    ["0"]=>
    string(3) "0-0"
    ["2"]=>
    string(3) "0-2"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#20 (2) {
    ["1"]=>
    string(3) "1-1"
    ["2"]=>
    string(3) "1-2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you don't have ongoing indexes in your array:

```
$test = array();
$test[0][0] = "0-0";
$test[0][2] = "0-2";
```

In this case `json_encode()` HAS to create an object because there is a numeric key (1) missing.

You can decode it back to an array with `json_decode($txt, true)`, but this is only a work around, not a fix.

Comment: THanks for the answer, that worked. In my particular application, it will be a 256x256 array but chances are every index won't be set. Would it be better to work with objects in the first place? Is there a performance difference?

Comment: There is no real performance difference on the JS side. On the PHP side there may be a small difference, but I would use arrays with ``json_decode($txt, true)`` or set the non-existing indexes to NULL - dunno what fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

By default json_decode will convert the json into objects. You code needs to look like:

`$recreated = json_decode($encoded, true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can decode as arrays:

```
$recreated = json_decode($encoded, true);
```